# how to load the content of a show method in laravel on the index method using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, laravel

i have two methods show and index
i have a list of items on the index method that when a user clicks it takes her to another page containing some data that belongs to that id. instead of doing it such way i want to use jquery to achieve this, to make the data load on the same page. i have the following on my index.blade.php view, please how do i achieve this in laravel

```
       @foreach ($categories as $category)

        <div class="body">
        <h4><a style="text-decoration: none; " href="{{ URL::route('category.show', $category->id) }}">{{$category->name}}</a></h4>

        </div>
       @endforeach

    <?php
     namespace App\Http\Controllers;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use illuminate\HttpResponse;
     use App\Http\Requests\todolistRequest;
     use App\Http\Requests\CreateCategoryRequest;
     use App\Http\Requests;
     use App\Companylist;
     use App\Category;
     use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
     class CategoryController extends Controller
     {

public function create(){
    return view('category.create');
}

public function index(){
    $categories=Category::all();
    return view('category.index',compact('categories'));
}
public function store(CreateCategoryRequest $request){
     $category = new Category($request->all());
     $category->save();

      return \Redirect::route('category.create')->with('message',      'Your list has been created!'); 
}
      public function show($id)
      {
      $category = Category::findOrFail($id)->companylist()->get();
      $cat=Category::findOrFail($id);
    // this my route
    Route::resource('category','CategoryController');

    return view('category.show')->with('category',     $category)->with('cat',$cat);
 }


//
}
```

Comment: Show your controllers code & routes

Comment: av updated the que @  ARIF MAHMUD RANA

Comment: arif, can you help, av updated the question

Answer (score 0):

To show details data on index page without page refreshing , you should use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) , in ajax return data and show it in index page ( i.e. under each list )

In ajax you have to pass the id and depending on id return corresponding data.

Hope it helps

Comment: i av done this using normal procedural php, so i need a laravel way of doing it.